# Why is my ::after text overlapping each other

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to display word's translation under each word of my text.

I tried to display translations in after blocks, but they are overlapping when translations are longer than original words.

```css
.word {
    position: relative;
    white-space: pre-line;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: inline;
}
.word::after {
    content: attr(disp);
    position: absolute;
    font-style: italic;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="word" disp="tr1">word1 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="tr2">word2 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="translated3">word3 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="translated4">word4
 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="tr5">word5 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="tr6">word6 </span>
</div>
```

Is there any way to position each next "block" of two words (original+translation) so it doesn't overlap the previous "block", but without any margin between "blocks" or making all "blocks" to be the same size?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

```css
.word {
    white-space: pre-line;
    line-height: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    float: left;     
}

.word::after {
    content: attr(disp);
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="word" disp="tr1">word1 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="tr2">word2 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="translated3">word3 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="translated4">word4
 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="tr5">word5 </span>
  <span class="word" disp="tr6">word6 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question or teach them how to do anything; it's just a different block of code that doesn't have the same problem.

Comment: Suggesting to *try* something, makes your answer look a bit wobbly. You should motivate your answer by adding details and explain why OP should use your method :)

Comment: @MehdiCharife The issue is not _only_ that it is "different code" (there are infinite different code snippets that also don't solve OP's problem). The issue is that it does not attempt to explain what the cause of OP's problem is, doesn't specify what you changed, or why you changed it/how it fixes OP's problem. A good answer explains the problem and the solution. It's the difference between handing someone a fish and teaching them to fish. Or at least, 'this is a fish and it has a lot more vitamins and minerals that you need than the Twinkie you've been eating', more accurately.